# How to find the user_location using Facebook api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I tried this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/locations
```

But didn't get what i wanted :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the location the user lives, according to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/, the User object has a property called location.  So when you try http://graph.facebook.com/me you will get an object with all user details including the user's current location; which has two subkeys ID and Name.

This can easily been seen here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me

Comment: Do you need the user's permission to get their location?